# Aggregating rows of lists in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Series that looks like this

```
index     column

A         [41, 13, 4, 50]

A         [41, 13, 4, 5]
.
.
.
```

What I want to do is aggregate the rows of lists, but only the unique values.

The result should look like this:

```
index     column
    
    A     [41, 13, 4, 50, 5]

.
.
.
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(df.explode('column') # explode list to bring values in rows
 .drop_duplicates()  # drop duplicates
 .groupby('index',as_index=False) # group on index
 .agg(list)) # aggregate as list
```

```
    index   column
0   A   [41, 13, 4, 50, 5]
```

if you have a **series** then

```
s.explode().drop_duplicates().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

```
A    [41, 13, 4, 50, 5]
B             [3, 2, 1]
dtype: object
```

**Data used**

```
s=pd.Series([[41, 13, 4, 50], [41, 13, 4, 5], [5,4,3], [5,2,1]], index=['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'])
s
```

```
A    [41, 13, 4, 50]
A     [41, 13, 4, 5]
B          [5, 4, 3]
B          [5, 2, 1]
dtype: object
```

Comment: It's telling me `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`

Comment: I think it's because it's a series and not a DataFrame

Comment: Also, the column labeled 'index' is the actual index column. Not sure how to refer to that in the groupby function.

Comment: @salamander, that is why it helps to share the right details in question. can you post the series that you have, so it won't turn into a trial and error. I'll take your series definition and update the solution.

Comment: added solution for series

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this:

```
df.groupby(df.index).column.apply(lambda x: x.explode().unique())
```

here you first group based on index, then expand everything and return the unique numbers as list

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [[41, 13, 4, 50], [41, 13, 4, 5], [5,4,3], [5,2,1]]}, index=['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'])

df.groupby(df.index).data.apply(lambda x: x.explode().unique())
```

[image]

Comment: But not just for the rows with index A. I tried to signify that with the ellipsis.

Comment: Sorry I named my column and row in the example "A", i renamed it to "data" or "column" (as you used). See if that works for you. If not please let me know what u mean exactly